# Работа с динамически подключаемой библиотекой

Tags: c#

Вопрос такой - как определять поля для объекта класса из динамически подгруженной библиотеки ? Как загрузить динамически dll, создать обьект класса и вызвать метод обьекта я нашел, а вот как быть со свойствами обьекта ?

Пример для SQLite:

```
Assembly a = Assembly.Load("System.Data.SQLite");
object obj = a.CreateInstance("System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection");
```

В рантайме программа знает что обьект `obj` это обьект класса `SQLiteConnection` но не ранее. Как мне присвоить полю `ConnectionString` какое либо значение ? Как установить свойствам этого класса значения ?

PS - к конкретно SQLite вопрос отношения не имеет, интересует сама технология.

UPD :
как добавить свойство разобрался, благодаря ссылке увожаемого @Igor :

```
obj.GetType().GetProperty("ConnectionString").SetValue(obj, "ConStr");
```

Однако возник другой вопрос - возвращаясь к той же SQLite, попробую присвоить для обьекта комманды обьект подключения :

```
sq_command.GetType().GetProperty("Connection").SetValue(sq_command, obj);
```

На что получаю исключение :

> Обнаружено неоднозначное соответствие

Как с этим быть ?

StackTrace

> в System.RuntimeType.GetPropertyImpl(String name, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Type returnType, Type[] types, ParameterModifier[] modifiers)
>
> в System.Type.GetProperty(String name)
>
> в ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args) в C:\Users\...Program.cs:строка 68"    string

Comment: Reflection: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619767/set-object-property-using-reflection

Comment: @Igor обновил вопрос

Comment: надо разбираться: разбейте цепочку вызовов на отдельные команды с промежуточными переменными, чтобы узнать, какой из вызовов приводит к ошибке

Comment: да, и полный StackTrace исключения добавьте, пожалуйста, в вопрос

Comment: @Igor добавил StackTrace

Comment: @Igor можно ли использовать конструктор ?

Comment: @Igor Помогло приведение интерфесов, но все равно спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос удалось решить гораздо проще - благодаря таким замечательным сущностям как интерфейсы C#. Достаточно просто явно привести обьекты к `IDbConnection` и `IDbDataAdapter`:

```
using (var sq_connection = (IDbConnection)a.CreateInstance("System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection"))
      {
          sq_connection.ConnectionString = ConnectionString;
          using (var sq_command = sq_connection.CreateCommand())
          {
              sq_command.CommandText = sql;
              sq_command.Connection = sq_connection;
              var sql_adapter = (IDbDataAdapter)a.CreateInstance("System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataAdapter");
              sql_adapter.SelectCommand = sq_command;
              sql_adapter.Fill(DB);
           }
      }
```